# how can i get download link for downloadable product which are added in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Downloadable product have multiple download link and i want to get link which added in cart.
I have tried this code but it gives all availbale links

```
$_links = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getLinks($_item->getProduct());
```

Comment: Please check the article, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-downloadable-product-links-from-product-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get link which added in cart:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (preg_match("/epub/i", $link->getTitle())) {
        $linkId = $link->getLinkId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that /epub/ string in the regex from?

Comment: Looks to me like he is just filtering the links for epub links.

Answer (score 1):

I developed solution for this issue..

```
$currentcart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $currentcart->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        $totalLinks = 0;
        $linkIds = "";
        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $ItemId = $item->getId();
            $options = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_option_collection');
            $options->addItemFilter($ItemId);
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option['code'] == 'downloadable_link_ids') {
                    $linkIds .= $option['value'] . ",";
                }
            }

        }
        $itemIds = substr($linkIds, 0, -1);
        //echo "Link Ids=" . $itemIds;
        $linkIdsArr = explode(',', $itemIds);
        //print_r($linkIdsArr);
        $totalLinks = count($linkIdsArr);
        //die;


        if ($totalLinks > 1) {
        //Get discount
        }
```

It worked for me.. try yourself..
find [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128175/get-downloadable-product-link-details-added-in-cart/128267#128267)