# Get downloadable product link details added in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, discount, download, download-link

I have ques.

I want to get downloadable products link added in cart..

Mean I want total links **added in cart**

I have used below code..

I am developing functionality to auto discount if downloadable products links are more than 2 in cart.

I created event

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Manoj_AutoDiscount>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Manoj_AutoDiscount>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <checkout>
        <rewrite>
          <observer>Manoj_AutoDiscount_Model_Observer</observer>
        </rewrite>
      </checkout>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        <observers>
          <checkoutApplyCouponToProduct>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Manoj_AutoDiscount_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>applyAutoDiscount</method>
          </checkoutApplyCouponToProduct>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <checkoutRemoveCouponAuto>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Manoj_AutoDiscount_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>removeAutoDiscount</method>
          </checkoutRemoveCouponAuto>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

and below method in observer

```
class Manoj_AutoDiscount_Model_Observer
{
    public function applyAutoDiscount($observer)
    {

$items =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $_links = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getLinks($item->getProduct());
echo count($_links)

            foreach ($_links as $link) {
                   // echo "<br/>Link ids".$linkId = $link->getLinkId();echo "<br/>";

            }
        }
}
}
```

Here I am getting all link of downloadable products.
I need only links added in cart only..
e.g  products has 3 links
and we added only 2 links in cart then i want record of 2 links only not of  3.

Can you please provide solution for same..
Appreciate your help..

Thanks in adavnce

Manoj Ninave

Answer (score 0):

Finally I developed solution for this issue..

```
$currentcart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $currentcart->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        $totalLinks = 0;
        $linkIds = "";
        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $ItemId = $item->getId();
            $options = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_option_collection');
            $options->addItemFilter($ItemId);
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option['code'] == 'downloadable_link_ids') {
                    $linkIds .= $option['value'] . ",";
                }
            }

        }
        $itemIds = substr($linkIds, 0, -1);
        //echo "Link Ids=" . $itemIds;
        $linkIdsArr = explode(',', $itemIds);
        //print_r($linkIdsArr);
        $totalLinks = count($linkIdsArr);
        //die;


        if ($totalLinks > 1) {
        //Get discount
        }
```

It worked for me.. 
try yourself..
Practice makes man Pefect ;)